# Android error on interstitial loadAd

Tags: android, admob, interstitial

I am trying to implement support for Interstitial Ads in my android app, which I'm hoping to publish soon.  I am encountering two problems for which I'm hoping someone might have some insight.  I have followed the most current instructions I could find from Google.

Firstly, I was wondering if there's an ad_unit_id I should use for testing Interstitial ads.  Right now I have `ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111` but I think that's only for testing banner ads?

Secondly, when I invoke `m_interstitial.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());` I get the following errors:

```
03-04 14:40:42.181: W/dalvikvm(30338): VFY: unable to resolve static method 3097: Landroid/webkit/WebSettings;.getDefaultUserAgent (Landroid/content/Context;)Ljava/lang/String;
03-04 14:40:42.922: W/dalvikvm(30338): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 159: Landroid/app/Notification$Builder;.setPriority (I)Landroid/app/Notification$Builder;
03-04 14:40:42.932: W/dalvikvm(30338): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 441: Landroid/content/pm/PackageManager;.getPackageInstaller ()Landroid/content/pm/PackageInstaller;
03-04 14:40:43.132: I/webclipboard(30338): clipservice: android.sec.clipboard.ClipboardExManager@4162a320
```

It looks like I'm missing something, but I've followed all the instructions I could find and can't figure out what's missing?

I'm using Eclipse for development.  According to SDK Manager, I'm using Google Play Services version 22, and Google Repository version 15.  Any insights would be greatly appreciated.  Thank you!

Comment: Mine is strictly an OpenGL app, so I don't have a layout - would I need to make one for the ads?

Comment: From what I can gather after doing further research, InterstitialAd is an object and not a view, and doesn't require any separate layout.  The main concern is the unresolved methods, it looks to me like there must be some libraries missing or something but I've included android-support-v4.jar in my libs folder, and I'm sure I properly followed the instructions for importing the google-play-services_lib into the project.

Comment: Okay, I've gathered a little more information - firstly the log messages seem to be warnings, so I'm disregarding them for now - but it is crashing, which is why I posted the question.  Right after I invoke:

    m_interstitial.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());

I get a crash in glsurfaceview$glthread.run(), it indicates Illegalstateexception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so I found the answers myself:

- For testing interstitial ads (and for banner ads), it's recommended that you use addTestDevice, as described [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/ads/InterstitialAd.html).  The device ID is emitted in your debug output when you run the app.
- The crash was caused by the ads being invoked from the OpenGL render thread.  They needed to either be called from the UI thread or in a thread-safe manner (using messages) from the other thread.